# native English speakers

Tags: adjectives, attributive-nouns

a. Native speaker men speak English differently than native speaker women.

b. Native speaking men speak English differently than native speaking women.

==========================

c. Native English speaker men speak English differently than native speaker women.

d. Native English speaking men speak English differently than native speaking women.

Which of the above sentences are grammatically correct?

I could one could go for 'male native speakers', but that would include minors.

Comment: This is coming dangerously close to proofreading! I don't think any of them is actually ungrammatical, but you could avoid a lot of unnecessary repetition by beginning "Among native speakers of English, men...".

Comment: Thank you for all your replies. I don't know how to prove it to you, but it is not proofreading. If I was writing something, I'd go for 'men whose first language is English,,,' or something of the sort.

Comment: **Native English speaker men** might not be *wrong*, but it sounds very un-natural.